# ax.patches for accessing the subplots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 with same columns. I am plotting a countplot in subplots to compare results side by side using

```py
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=[16,4])
```

I want to annotate the percentage in the Bar for count plot. so, I need to divide the bar height with the total length.

Below is my code:

```py
total = len(df_1[col])
for p in ax.patches:
    percentage = '{:.1f}%'.format(100 * p.get_height()/total)
    x = p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2 - 0.05
    y = p.get_y() + p.get_height()/2
    ax.annotate(percentage, (x, y),rotation=90, size = 10)
```

My Problem is, in the above code I am unable to distinguish `ax[0]` and `ax[1]` based on which I can change the value of total variable. Hence, it is not calculating the percentage of my second subplot correctly.

[image: Subplots]

Comment: Your code `for p in ax.patches` would give an error as shown.  You need `fig,axs = plt.subplots(1,2,...)`.  And then `for ax, df in zip(axs, [df_1, df_2]):` with `total = len(df)` and `for p in ax.patches: ....`